# HDFS Namenode High Availability

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, high-availability

I enabled the Namenode High Availability using ambari.
I want to verify the connection using dfs.nameservices (nameservice ID) before start the coding.
Is there any command line or tool to verifiy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the normal HDFS CLI.

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://nameservice/user
```

Which should also work the same as

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs:///user
```

Or giving your active namenode

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://namenode-1:port/user
```

If you provide the standby namenode, it will say `operation READ not supported in state standby`